# Is jQuery too heavy to use on Tablets?

Tags: jquery, tablet

When making a web page which works on an app on iPad, is jQuery heavy? some of my friends who experienced my app said some page's CSS effects aren't working quickly. However a web page itself on Chrome works fine.

I imported jQuery, but the usage of it is limited like adding classes to make CSS animation and manipulating DOM elements.

What factors would make my App slower? App on Tablets? or jQuery?

Comment: `like adding classes to make CSS animation and manipulating DOM elements.` Then why use jQuery at all? Vanilla JS can accomplish those sorts of things just as easily

Comment: why not run some benchmark tests yourself? :)

Comment: jQuery itself is fine to use on tablets and low power devices. However you'll need to be more aware of the performance limitations of the devices when you write the logic.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks. I can code with Vanilla JS, but I wanna know if jQuery  is really a matter that slower an application. Global usage prove that many sites are made of it. My job is kind of outsourcing I only make some pages woking on iPad, so I'd like to know if iPad app is slow or the way i make a web application make it slow

Comment: @treyBake Thanks, what is benchmark tests?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks for replying. I think I need to study more on performance

Comment: @WonBokLee https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benchmark_(computing) :) essentially speed testing, just set up a timer, run your jQuery on a desktop, mobile and tablet and compare results of numerous function being run 100s of times. Get the avg. speed and compare that :)

Comment: Yes, jQuery may well degrade performance on lower-power machines - it's not a trivial amount of code, after all.

Answer (score -1):

No, jQuery is not to heavy. You can use CDN as source, then it's a higher chance it's already cached by the browser. I would recommend looking at GSAP for smoother animations https://greensock.com/